# PySpark SQL operation in Pandas to compute the drive ages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to sample data based on operational hours. For example, Serial C was introduced in 2014-01-01 and it was was failed in 2014-01-03.  Serial B, and D was never failed. I want to compute the operational hours as follows:
[image]

I was able to do it using PySpark as follows:

PySpark version:

```
drive_spans = spark.sql("""
select
    serial_number,
    max(date) as retired_date,
    min(date) as launched_date,
    count(date) as observed_days,
    min(case when failure=1 then date end) as failed_date,
    max(smart_187_raw) as max_hours,
    min(case when failure=1 then smart_187_raw end) as failed_hours,
    max(failure) as failure
from df
group by serial_number
""").cache()
drive_spans.count()

dfsurv = spark.sql("""
select
    drive_spans.*,
    datediff(coalesce(failed_date, retired_date), launched_date) as duration,
    min(launched_date) over (partition by serial_number) as model_introduced
from drive_spans
""")
```

However, I couldn't use the same PySpark functionality in Pandas. I appreciate your suggestions for the following dataframe. I wanna get the above table for this data. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/e464ca4da5c871428ca9ed9264467aa0/raw/da3921c1953fefbc66dddc3ce238dac53142dba8/failure.csv',sep='\t')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(by="date")
gb = df.groupby(['serial_number'])
gb.agg(
    first_date=('date', np.min),
    last_date=('date', np.max)
).reset_index()
```

Comment: If you already have the SQL written out, you can just use the same query on top of Pandas with Fugue: https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/quick_look/ten_minutes_sql.html

Comment: How about `dfsurv.toPandas()`? You would get the Pandas output right away